# Stop jQuery with media query

Tags: jquery, media

Simple question can I stop a jquery function with media queries.

I have a jQuery slideshow that I want to stop when the window gets to phone size so i can adjust the layout.

Comment: See this: http://www.venveo.com/articles/view/quick-tip-jquery-media-queries

Answer (score 1):

`Media Queries` are a `CSS3` concept and not a javascript feature. So utilising media queries in javascript means, in supporting implementations, querying the CSS API of the browser for values.

### Confused?

`window.matchMedia()` is what you call from javascript as such

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );
if (mq.matches) {  
    // window width is at least 500px  
}  
else {  
    // window width is less than 500px  
}
```

Which in turn brings us to the classical question, "*what is the browser support for it?*"!
In my opinion, pretty low as this relies on functionalities more commonly found in *modern* browsers.

### Any Hope?

There is a `js` project that allows enquiring about the state of affairs from the browser, encapsulated behind clean api calls called [Enquire.js](http://wickynilliams.github.com/enquire.js/) with some [explaination and tuts](http://css-tricks.com/enquire-js-media-query-callbacks-in-javascript/)

### Source:

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, although someone may be able to prove me wrong;

We handle a similar kind of issue on our websites by re-arranging our menus if the screen width is less than 768px. So you could do something like this on document.ready()

```
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
  // Start jquery slideshow here
}
```

We also account for the browser being resized by doing something like below by wrapping the width check in a function.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
            StartSlideshow();
        });

function StartSlideshow() {
    if ($(window).width() > 767) {
      // Start jquery slideshow here
    }
}
```

If you do this you'll also need to call the function on document.ready!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean css3 media queries, I don't know a way you can.

But something like this:

```
function windowSizeCheck(){
  if($(window).width() > (minSizeforSlideShow) && $(window).height() > (minHeightforSlideShow){
    doSlideShowStuff();
  }
}
```

...might do the trick. Call it on load and resize events ( `$(window).resize()` )